# Getting hudson.remoting.ChannelClosedException error in Jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, google-kubernetes-engine

I have an error while running a pipeline in Jenkins using a Kubernetes Cloud server.

Everything works fine until the moment of the `npm install` where i get `Cannot contact nodejs-rn5f3: hudson.remoting.ChannelClosedException: Channel "hudson.remoting.Channel@3b1e0041:nodejs-rn5f3": Remote call on nodejs-rn5f3 failed. The channel is closing down or has closed down`

How can I fix this error ?

Here are my logs :

```
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] podTemplate
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] node
Still waiting to schedule task
‘nodejs-rn5f3’ is offline
Agent nodejs-rn5f3 is provisioned from template nodejs
---
apiVersion: "v1"
kind: "Pod"
metadata:
  labels:
    jenkins: "slave"
    jenkins/label-digest: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    jenkins/label: "nodejs"
  name: "nodejs-rn5f3"
spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - "cat"
    command:
    - "/bin/sh"
    - "-c"
    image: "node:15.5.1-alpine3.10"
    imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
    name: "node"
    resources:
      limits: {}
      requests: {}
    tty: true
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/home/jenkins/agent"
      name: "workspace-volume"
      readOnly: false
    workingDir: "/home/jenkins/agent"
  - env:
    - name: "JENKINS_SECRET"
      value: "********"
    - name: "JENKINS_AGENT_NAME"
      value: "nodejs-rn5f3"
    - name: "JENKINS_WEB_SOCKET"
      value: "true"
    - name: "JENKINS_NAME"
      value: "nodejs-rn5f3"
    - name: "JENKINS_AGENT_WORKDIR"
      value: "/home/jenkins/agent"
    - name: "JENKINS_URL"
      value: "http://XX.XX.XX.XX/"
    image: "jenkins/inbound-agent:4.3-4"
    name: "jnlp"
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: "100m"
        memory: "256Mi"
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/home/jenkins/agent"
      name: "workspace-volume"
      readOnly: false
  hostNetwork: false
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/os: "linux"
  restartPolicy: "Never"
  volumes:
  - emptyDir:
      medium: ""
    name: "workspace-volume"

Running on nodejs-rn5f3 in /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/something
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test)
[Pipeline] checkout
Selected Git installation does not exist. Using Default
[... cloning repository]
[Pipeline] container
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ ls -la
total 1240
drwxr-xr-x    5 node     node          4096 Feb 26 07:33 .
drwxr-xr-x    4 node     node          4096 Feb 26 07:33 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 node     node          1689 Feb 26 07:33 package.json
and some other files and folders
[Pipeline] sh
+ cat package.json
{
  [...]
  "dependencies": {
    [blabla....]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    [blabla...]
  }
}
[Pipeline] sh
+ npm install
Cannot contact nodejs-rn5f3: hudson.remoting.ChannelClosedException: Channel "hudson.remoting.Channel@3b1e0041:nodejs-rn5f3": Remote call on nodejs-rn5f3 failed. The channel is closing down or has closed down
```

At this stage, here are the logs of the container `jnlp` in my pod `nodejs-rnf5f3` :

```
INFO: Connected
Feb 26, 2021 8:05:53 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Read side closed
Feb 26, 2021 8:05:53 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Terminated
Feb 26, 2021 8:05:53 AM jenkins.slaves.restarter.JnlpSlaveRestarterInstaller$FindEffectiveRestarters$1 onReconnect
INFO: Restarting agent via jenkins.slaves.restarter.UnixSlaveRestarter@1a39588e
Feb 26, 2021 8:05:55 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main createEngine
INFO: Setting up agent: nodejs-rnf5f3
Feb 26, 2021 8:05:55 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener <init>
INFO: Jenkins agent is running in headless mode.
Feb 26, 2021 8:05:55 AM hudson.remoting.Engine startEngine
INFO: Using Remoting version: 4.3
Feb 26, 2021 8:05:55 AM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager initializeWorkDir
INFO: Using /home/jenkins/agent/remoting as a remoting work directory
Feb 26, 2021 8:05:55 AM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager setupLogging
INFO: Both error and output logs will be printed to /home/jenkins/agent/remoting
Feb 26, 2021 8:05:55 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: WebSocket connection open
Feb 26, 2021 8:05:58 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connected
.... same as above
```

I don't know where this error come from. Is this related to the usage of resources ?

Here are the usage of my containers :

```
POD                   NAME             CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)
jenkins-1-jenkins-0   jenkins-master   61m          674Mi
nodejs-rnf5f3         jnlp             468m         104Mi
nodejs-rnf5f3         node             1243m        1284Mi
```

My cluster is a `e2-medium` in GKE with 2 nodes.

Answer (score 2):

If I had to bet (but its just a wild guess) I had say that the pod was killed due to running out of memory (OOM Killed).

The ChannelClosedException is a symptom, not the problem.

Its kind of hard to debug because the agent pod is being deleted, you can try `kubectl get events` in the relevant namespace, but events only last for 1 hour by default.